# GNU Octave: use textscan() function to read sequence of integers separated by a dot (.)

Tags: octave, textscan

I am trying to read data from a file with dates in DAY.MONTH.YEAR format using the textscan(...) function. Below is a simple illustration of the problem.

This does not work as desired:

```
    u = textscan ('5.2.1975','%d.%d.%d')
    u = 
    {
      [1,1] = 5
      [1,2] = 1975
      [1,3] = 0
    }
```

It seems textscan treats the 5.2 part as a decimal number and rounds it to 5. It returns the last number (1975) as the second element of u.

The conversion works as expected if the separator is not a dot:

```
    u = textscan ('5*2*1975','%d*%d*%d')
    u = 
    {
      [1,1] = 5
      [1,2] = 2
      [1,3] = 1975
    }
```

What do I need to change to make it work with the dot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I observe in Octave 4.0.3:

```
>>  u = textscan ('5.2.1975','%d.%d.%d')
u =
{
  [1,1] = 5
  [1,2] = 2
  [1,3] = 1975
}
```

So it seems that `textscan` does exactly what you expect, in principle.

If you are seeing a different result:

- in an older Octave release, you should upgrade your version of Octave and check again;
- in a recent release, you should report this as a bug on the [Octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave).

Comment: I am using Octave 4.2. I'll try the bug tracker then.